# C++ how to remove puncuation from a string array?

Tags: c++, punctuation

In the following program showed below I attempted to remove all puncuation from a string array using ispunct

```
std::string fileName;
std::fstream readFile;
const int arraySize = 50000;
std::string storeFile[arraySize];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

for (int i = 0, len = storeFile[i].size(); i < len; i++) {  
 
if (ispunct(storeFile[i])){//check whether parsing character is punctuation or not
          
storeFile[i].erase(std::remove_if(storeFile[i].begin(), 
                                  storeFile[i].end(),
                                  ::ispunct), storeFile[i].end());
    
            }     
        }
}
```

However I recieve the following error on for `ispunct(storeFile[i]`

`function "ispunct" cannot be called with the given argument list -- argument types are: (std::string)`

Ive used ispunct before for std::string but not a std::string array[]. How can I remove puncuation and white space from a string array? Thankyou

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        while (readFile >> storeFile[i])
        {
            std::transform(storeFile[i].begin(), storeFile[i].end(), storeFile[i].begin(), ::tolower);

            for (auto &s : storeFile)
            {
                s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ::ispunct), s.end());
                s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ::isspace), s.end());
            }


             }
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to remove punctuation from all the strings in the array or just one?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen all strings of the array

Comment: @rustyx i did try removing ```if (ispunct(storeFile[i])) ``` but it removes everything(all characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ispunct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct) takes 1 character as input, not an entire string.

But you don't need to check the string before removing the punctuation. Something simple like this will work:

```
    for (auto& s : storeFile) {
        s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ::ispunct), s.end());
    }
```

[**Live demo**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n3sTPo)

==EDIT==

You have a fixed array of 50000 strings. If the input file contains N strings, you'll print that followed by 50000-N blank lines. It's probably not what you want. Use `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

```
    std::string s;
    std::vector<std::string> storeFile;
    while (readFile >> s) {
        std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::tolower);
        s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ::ispunct), s.end());
        s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ::isspace), s.end());
        storeFile.push_back(std::move(s));
    }
```

Comment: Ive added my implementation of this code to the end of my question as when i attempt to use the data/print it. Nothing returns.

Comment: The `for` loop should go after the `while` loop, not inside it (is not the cause of your issue though). Maybe `readFile >> storeFile[i]` isn't reading the strings as you expect, did you check that?

Comment: see i tried doing ```std::cout << s << std::endl;``` but this happens. ill attach an imagestd(https://i.imgur.com/lhUTT4m.png) IE just blank space

Comment: but then without the std::endl; I get this as an output (https://i.imgur.com/TfAqN7x.png) which isnt what I need hahah

Comment: should output more along the lines of this (https://i.imgur.com/IXXtxYt.png)

Comment: God i really do appreciate the help so i feel bad for not mentioning this earlier but this is for a university level task so we're not allowed to use vectors for storage! I need to work using the array[500000], though the size isnt a big problem its more of a sugguestion

Comment: Well, then you need to keep track of how many strings you've read and print only that many strings, or skip empty strings when printing.

Comment: how would I go about the skip empty strings option?

Comment: `if (!str.empty()) { /* print str */ }`

Comment: str would be the array element. You didn't show your printing code. But something like this: `for (auto& s : storeFile) if (!s.empty()) std::cout << s << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

With C++20, its actually just one line of code:

Consider you have a string `str`:

```
std::erase_if(vec, ispunct);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `std::erase_if(str, ispunct)`, but then inside a for-loop over `vec`?

Comment: @rustyx, Is it a vec in my answer?